# Delphi xe , unit dbExcept , not found. was in delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

In the db, did Embarcadero removed the dbExcept?

Was it removed or replaced?

What could replace it?

Comment: The database (BDE) errors and exceptions seems to be moved to unit `Bde.DbTables.pas` and `TDBError` class. See [TDBError](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Bde.DBTables.TDBError).

Comment: Its documented in XE2, [EDBEngineError](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Bde.DBTables.EDBEngineError). I don't have the database version, so I can't check.

Answer (score 1):

That unit and the code it contains has gone. But it doesn't look as if it actually did anything. I suspect it was vestigial code that had long ceased being used but was left in place. The code in that unit was not referred to by any other source code unit supplied with Delphi.

I expect you have a stray `DbExcept` in your uses clause that can simply be removed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be part of Borland Database Engine (BDE), which is deprecated. Is it installed?